# Matlab command window minimize

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am running a GUI in MATLAB. I want whenever my GUI gets opened MATLAB command window should be minimized?

I have tried with WindowAPI but it is not working. Please give some suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/19626)?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Matlab's Java support, thereby manipulating the (undocumented) Java objects that make up the Matlab IDE. As far as I know, the Command Window is always embedded in the main Matlab Desktop Window, so here's the code to minimize that.

Get a reference to the Java object that implements the Matlab Desktop:

```
desktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance();
```

Get a reference to the window (Java Frame) that contains the Desktop:

```
mf = desktop.getMainFrame();
```

Minimize it:

```
mf.setMinimized(true);
```

This approach works across platforms.

See http://undocumentedmatlab.com/ for more information on the undocumented internals of Matlab.